# Agrupar registros por meses y obtener incluso los meses que no tengan ningún registro

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola estoy intentando obtener los registros con valor cero de una consulta con `count` y valores agrupados por fecha. Ahora mismo tengo esto:

```
select count(idfirma) as firmas,month(fecha)as mes,year(fecha) as anyo from firma,clientes WHERE clientes.idcliente=firma.idcliente group by month(fecha) order by fecha asc limit 7
```

El problema es que obtengo los meses que tienen datos pero me gustaría obtener los meses o últimos seis meses en concreto que no tengan datos o registros.

Los últimos seis meses que aparezca el `count` con valor 0 cuando no haya registros y el valor que sea cuando si tenga registros o datos.

Answer (score 1):

Quieres obtener los últimos seis meses que no tengan datos, eso no es posible de la forma que lo estas haciendo, ya que esa información NO EXISTE como lo dijiste.

Necesitas crear una tabla temporal con los meses:

```
declare @UltimosSeisMeses table (
    mes int,
    anio int
);

declare @mesActual int;
declare @anioActual int;

set @mesActual = month(getdate());
set @anioActual = year(getdate());

DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=6)--Los ultimos seis meses, sin contar el mes actual
BEGIN
    set @mesActual = @mesActual -1
    if(@mesActual = 0)
    begin
        set @mesActual = 12;
        set @anioActual = @anioActual-1;
    end
    insert into @UltimosSeisMeses values(@mesActual, @anioActual)
    SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END


select 
    m.anio as anyo,
    m.mes as mes,
    count(idfirma) as firmas
    --month(fecha)as mes,
    --year(fecha) as anyo 
from @UltimosSeisMeses m
    left outer join firmas f                
        on month(f.fecha) = m.mes
        and year(f.fecha) = m.anio
    left join clientes c
        on c.idcliente = f.idcliente
where f.idFirma is null  --comenta esta linea para ver todos los resultados
group by m.anio,m.mes
order by m.anio asc,m.mes asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer algo así:

```
SELECT COUNT(idfirma) AS firmas
,MONTH(fecha) AS mes
,YEAR(fecha) AS anyo
FROM 
(
  SELECT 1 as ID UNION SELECT 2 as ID UNION  SELECT 3 as ID UNION SELECT 4 as ID 
  UNION  
  SELECT 5 as ID UNION SELECT 6 as ID UNION SELECT 7 as ID UNION SELECT 8 as ID 
  UNION  
  SELECT 9 as ID UNION SELECT 10 as ID UNION SELECT 11 as ID UNION SELECT 12 as ID
) as Meses
LEFT JOIN `firma` ON Meses.ID = MONTH(`firma`.fecha)
,clientes
WHERE clientes.idcliente = firma.idcliente
GROUP BY MONTH(fecha)
ORDER BY fecha ASC LIMIT 7
```

No sé si de esa forma te funcione, o sea la sintaxis correcta, pero el truco lo hace la adición de ese `FROM` **Meses**. Has los cambios necesarios a tu necesidad.